# Ajax Calender Extender not working in Asp.net Web Application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to use calender extender from Ajax toolkit but it not showing in targeted textbox.

I'm using this code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate1" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDate1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDate1">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Then I even put Script Manager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

and this,

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Which may be the reason for this? Any help?

Comment: You tagged this question as JavaScript and jQuery. Why? Did you try debugging in the browser debugger and see a JavaScript error?

Comment: Check in your bin folder you have AjaxControlToolkit.dll and AjaxControlToolkit.pdb are available or not ?

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit.dll is in but not AjaxControlToolkit.pdb. Any reference to add??

Comment: download ajaxcontroltoolkit from   http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091       and add all language pack along with .pdb and .dll file inside your bin folder.

Comment: Since you are using the ajax control toolkit you will need to use ToolScriptManager instead of just ScriptManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing ScriptManager with ToolkitScriptManager

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

and make sure your ToolkitScriptManager is right after your

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this question as jQuery, might I suggest an alternative? jQuery UI has an excellent datepicker, if you're willing to add jQuery UI to your project.

```
$(function () {
     $("#<%=txtDate1.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
});
```