# Calendar extender not working in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, toolkitscriptmanager

I am trying to add Calendar Extender using AJAX on my web application. I am trying to popup calendar on click of textbox. I have tried all steps as mentioned here [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690709/ajax-calender-extender-not-working-in-asp-net-web-application)

I have redownloaded AJAX TOOLKIT 4.5 and pasted it in bin folder.
But nothing happens.
My codes are:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtfrom" PopupButtonID="txtfrom"></ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

So let me know what I a missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Also did you get an error message? If so put that in it might help for better answers.

Comment: No error message it does not popup

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ToolkitScriptManager is right after your

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

Comment: I dont have <form> tag on my page

Comment: oh, sorry try having it before the extender.

Comment: so should I put like this <form id="form1" runat="server"><ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtfrom" PopupButtonID="txtfrom"></ajax:CalendarExtender></form>

Comment: I tried that but it gave error:
`A page can have only one server-side Form tag.`

Comment: any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the appropriate .NET framework that corresponds with your AJAXControlToolkit.dll and that it is correctly added as a Reference in your project.

If you go to your browser's developer tools (F12 in firefox and IE) and check out the console output, it should give you some errors regarding the AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: I am on console output, but its blank nothings there. I am also using firebug on firefox

Comment: Go to your references and right click AjaxControlToolkit and go to Properties.  What is the Runtime Version listed?